# aapt erros when generating resource ids

Tags: android, aapt

I was using the "Extract Android String" option under the Android menu in eclipse and suddenly aapt crashes when generating my resource (R) file. I'm at a complete loss here.  I've gotten it to compile once by switching the target API in both projects from 15 to 16 and back but it seems like it was a fluke.

I'm using Actinbar Sherlock and it poops when generating some of its resource IDs.  Actionbar Sherlock builds just find its my project that uses ActionBar Sherlock that fails.

I turned on the verbose logging for builds and you can see it just crashes in the middle of a print statement.

```
... Many working lines like the one below removed...
[2012-11-26 00:32:36 - MyProject]     (new resource id abs__action_bar_tab_bar_view from /.../ActionBarSherlock/library/res/layout/abs__action_bar_tab_bar_view.xml)
[2012-11-26 00:32:36 - MyProject]     (new resource id abs__action_bar_title_item from /.../ActionBarSherlock/library/res/layout/abs__action_bar_title_item.xml)
[2012-11-26 00:32:39 - MyProject]     (new resource id abs__action_m
[2012-11-26 00:32:39 - MyProject] 'aapt' error. Pre Compiler Build aborted.
```

edit: I have removed all of my Actionbar Sherlock dependencies and still have the same problem

```
[2012-11-26 12:22:11 - MyProject]     (new resource id details_title from /.../res/layout/details_title.xml)
[2012-11-26 12:22:13 - MyProject]     (new resource id event_details from /.../res/layout/even
[2012-11-26 12:22:13 - MyProject] 'aapt' error. Pre Compiler Build aborted.
[2012-11-26 12:22:14 - MyProject] Starting full Package build.
```

As you can see it broke during compiling event_details.xml so I just removed the file all together and it generated my R file, but it seems to be a fluke, I added the event again, it failed as I expected, I removed the event file again and now i fails on a different file.

Anyone know whats going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reverted all of my changes and then added them back one by one without using the refactor tool in the plugin and the problem went away. My guess is the refactoring tool somehow corrupted one of my files.  Use at your own risk :)